# GSuite Calendar Add-on: Show information during the creation process of an event

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, gsuite-addons

I want to create a [GSuite Add on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/calendar) for the Google Calendar where the user gets additional information during the creation process of an event.

For example: The user is in the creation process of an event and selects a specific resource for that event. (the event is not yet created). In the addon, there should be additional information about that ressource when the user selects this specific resource.

However the only there are only two triggers for the calendar add-on which are `eventOpen` and `eventUpdate` which both require and existing event.

So my question is how to interact between an Gsuite Calendar Add-on and an event in the creation phase.

Comment: Hi zlZimon! I don't think there are other event triggers for Calendar Add-ons currently, so no go. How about changing the flow a little and creating the event from the add-on from scratch using only the homepage trigger? Say, the user fills in all info in the sidebar, then clicked save.

Comment: But wouldn't that mean, that I basically have to re-programm the complete event creation process? With all the ressources which can be added, invites etc?

Comment: well, kinda... that might be too much, of course, I don't say anything. Although that at least is an interesting project to do :) Other than that I think we will have to wait until the new G Suite Add-ons platform gets some bulk until we get extra features, and that might take a while.

Comment: You can create a feature request on the issue tracker, and I will be happy to star and share with other active users so it gets more visibility. Also, stop by the community chat room (if no one invited you yet: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217630/google-apps-script-chat-community)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you want cannot be achieved.

What you can do instead is to file a **Feature Request** by accessing this link [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=642720&template=1392206) and provide all the necessary details.